# RSI function is failing to return any meaningful outcome

Tags: php, algorithmic-trading

I'd like to calculate RSI values of /ES but the function doesn't work. I can't figure out where I'm making a mistake. Can you help?

Here's the input data, printed with `print_r($data)`.

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 2859.50
>     [1] => 2859.00
>     [2] => 2859.75
>     [3] => 2857.25
>     [4] => 2860.25
>     [5] => 2861.50
>     [6] => 2860.75
>     [7] => 2862.00
>     [8] => 2856.00
>     [9] => 2853.25
>     [10] => 2852.50
>     [11] => 2850.75
>     [12] => 2854.00
>     [13] => 2852.00
>     [14] => 2847.75
>     [15] => 2847.00
>     [16] => 2847.00
>     [17] => 2855.75
>     [18] => 2854.00
>     [19] => 2860.00
>     [20] => 2866.50
>     [21] => 2866.75
>     [22] => 2866.25
>     [23] => 2865.75
>     [24] => 2868.75
>     [25] => 2862.75
>     [26] => 2863.75
>     [27] => 2863.75
>     [28] => 2859.75
>     [29] => 2854.25
>     [30] => 2858.25
>     [31] => 2858.75
>     [32] => 2862.50
>     [33] => 2868.50
>     [34] => 2887.00
>     [35] => 2889.25
>     [36] => 2883.75
>     [37] => 2887.50
>     [38] => 2888.00
>     [39] => 2884.50
>     [40] => 2883.00
>     [41] => 2882.00
>     [42] => 2879.00
>     [43] => 2881.00
>     [44] => 2881.50
>     [45] => 2884.75
>     [46] => 2887.75
>     [47] => 2885.75
>     [48] => 2886.00
>     [49] => 2882.25
>     [50] => 2878.25
>     [51] => 2876.50
>     [52] => 2874.75
>     [53] => 2872.00
>     [54] => 2873.25
>     [55] => 2877.75
>     [56] => 2868.50
>     [57] => 2863.00
>     [58] => 2863.50
>     [59] => 2861.25
>     [60] => 2862.25
>     [61] => 2863.25
>     [62] => 2862.00
>     [63] => 2855.75
>     [64] => 2853.50
>     [65] => 2855.50
>     [66] => 2857.50
>     [67] => 2854.75
>     [68] => 2853.25
>     [69] => 2848.50
>     [70] => 2851.00
>     [71] => 2850.25
>     [72] => 2849.00
>     [73] => 2840.50
>     [74] => 2842.00
>     [75] => 2834.00
>     [76] => 2848.00
>     [77] => 2861.25
>     [78] => 2860.75
>     [79] => 2860.75
>     [80] => 2861.25
>     [81] => 2854.25
>     [82] => 2851.75
>     [83] => 2851.25
>     [84] => 2847.00
>     [85] => 2847.75
>     [86] => 2851.25
>     [87] => 2847.00
>     [88] => 2848.00
>     [89] => 2848.00
>     [90] => 2848.25
>     [91] => 2849.50
>     [92] => 2846.25
>     [93] => 2845.50
>     [94] => 2847.25
>     [95] => 2841.75
>     [96] => 2842.00
>     [97] => 2844.75
>     [98] => 2843.00
>     [99] => 2844.00
>     [100] => 2844.00
>     [101] => 2846.50
>     [102] => 2846.00
>     [103] => 2847.25
>     [104] => 2845.50
>     [105] => 2840.50
>     [106] => 2840.75
>     [107] => 2839.25
>     [108] => 2836.00
>     [109] => 2833.50
>     [110] => 2836.00
>     [111] => 2831.25
>     [112] => 2829.25
>     [113] => 2827.75
>     [114] => 2828.75
>     [115] => 2827.50
>     [116] => 2829.75
>     [117] => 2832.25
>     [118] => 2829.25
>     [119] => 2827.50
>     [120] => 2826.00
>     [121] => 2825.25
>     [122] => 2833.00
>     [123] => 2833.75
>     [124] => 2829.25
>     [125] => 2824.50
>     [126] => 2821.25
>     [127] => 2808.75
>     [128] => 2811.75
>     [129] => 2813.50
>     [130] => 2810.75
>     [131] => 2805.75
>     [132] => 2804.50
>     [133] => 2804.25
>     [134] => 2807.50
>     [135] => 2810.00
>     [136] => 2815.25
>     [137] => 2810.25
>     [138] => 2810.75
>     [139] => 2812.75
>     [140] => 2806.50
>     [141] => 2808.50
>     [142] => 2803.75
>     [143] => 2811.00
>     [144] => 2808.00
>     [145] => 2809.50
>     [146] => 2802.50
>     [147] => 2793.50
>     [148] => 2804.25
>     [149] => 2804.25
>     [150] => 2801.50
>     [151] => 2804.25
>     [152] => 2806.50
>     [153] => 2803.00
>     [154] => 2800.00
>     [155] => 2798.75
>     [156] => 2797.75
>     [157] => 2795.00
>     [158] => 2796.50
>     [159] => 2799.25
>     [160] => 2798.25
>     [161] => 2797.75
>     [162] => 2796.25
>     [163] => 2790.75
>     [164] => 2784.25
>     [165] => 2787.00
>     [166] => 2794.50
>     [167] => 2795.25
>     [168] => 2799.25
>     [169] => 2800.75
>     [170] => 2800.75
>     [171] => 2804.50
>     [172] => 2798.00
>     [173] => 2804.75
>     [174] => 2809.75
>     [175] => 2808.75
>     [176] => 2801.50
>     [177] => 2803.50
>     [178] => 2794.50
>     [179] => 2795.50
>     [180] => 2799.75
>     [181] => 2799.50
>     [182] => 2798.50
>     [183] => 2797.75
>     [184] => 2796.50
>     [185] => 2803.75
>     [186] => 2806.50
>     [187] => 2803.25
>     [188] => 2798.75
>     [189] => 2799.50
>     [190] => 2795.00
>     [191] => 2795.00
>     [192] => 2793.00
>     [193] => 2789.25
>     [194] => 2793.75
>     [195] => 2788.50
>     [196] => 2789.25
>     [197] => 2782.75
>     [198] => 2775.75
>     [199] => 2781.50
> )
> ```

Here's the function.

```
function xrun($data, $period = 14){

    $change_array = array();

    //loop data
    foreach($data as $key => $row){

        //need 2 points to get change
        if($key >= 1){

            $change = $data[$key]['close'] - $data[$key - 1]['close'];

            //add to front
            array_unshift($change_array, $change);

            //pop back if too long
            if(count($change_array) > $period)
                array_pop($change_array);
        }

        //have enough data to calc rsi
        if($key > $period){
            //reduce change array getting sum loss and sum gains
            $res = array_reduce($change_array, function($result, $item) { 

                        if($item >= 0)
                            $result['sum_gain'] += $item;

                        if($item < 0)
                            $result['sum_loss'] += abs($item);

                        return $result; 
                    }, array('sum_gain' => 0, 'sum_loss' => 0)); 


            $avg_gain = $res['sum_gain'] / $period;
            $avg_loss = $res['sum_loss'] / $period;

            //check divide by zero
            if($avg_loss == 0){
                $rsi = 100;
            } else {
                //calc and normalize
                $rs = $avg_gain / $avg_loss;                
                $rsi = 100 - (100 / ( 1 + $rs));
            }

            //save
            $data[$key]['val'] = $rsi;

        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

It should output an array whose values are between 0 and 100 but it outputs $data as is, except the values are 1000 lower after the 14th element. Which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"RSI function is failing to return any meaningful outcome"* ?

Well, this polished code works fine :

```
<?php
// _____________________________________________________________________

function xrun( $data, $period = 14 ){
    $change_array = array();
    foreach( $data as $key => $row ){                                   // loop data
        if( $key >= 1 ){                                                // need 2 points to get change
            $change = $data[$key]['close'] - $data[$key - 1]['close'];
            array_unshift( $change_array, $change );                    // add to front
            if( count( $change_array ) > $period )                      // pop back if too long
                array_pop( $change_array );
        }
        if( $key > $period ){                                           // have enough data to calc rsi
            $res = array_reduce( $change_array,
                                  function( $result, $item ) {          // reduce change array getting sum loss and sum gains
                                                 if( $item >= 0 )
                                                     $result['sum_gain'] +=      $item;
                                                 if( $item <  0 )
                                                     $result['sum_loss'] += abs( $item );
                                                 return $result;
                                  },
                                  array( 'sum_gain' => 0,
                                         'sum_loss' => 0
                                         )
                                  );
            $avg_gain = $res['sum_gain'] / $period;
            $avg_loss = $res['sum_loss'] / $period;
            if( $avg_loss == 0 ){                                       // check divide by zero
                $rsi = 100;
            } else {
                $rs  = $avg_gain / $avg_loss;                           // calc and normalize
                $rsi = 100 - ( 100 / ( 1 + $rs ) );
            }
            $data[$key]['val'] = $rsi;                                  // save
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
// _____________________________________________________________________

$demoArray = array(
             array( "close" => 2859.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2859.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2859.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2857.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2860.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2861.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2860.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2862.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2856.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2853.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2852.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2850.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2854.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2852.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2855.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2854.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2860.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2866.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2866.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2866.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2865.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2868.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2862.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2863.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2863.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2859.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2854.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2858.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2858.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2862.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2868.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2887.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2889.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2883.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2887.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2888.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2884.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2883.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2882.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2879.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2881.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2881.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2884.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2887.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2885.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2886.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2882.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2878.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2876.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2874.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2872.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2873.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2877.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2868.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2863.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2863.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2861.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2862.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2863.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2862.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2855.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2853.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2855.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2857.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2854.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2853.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2848.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2851.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2850.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2849.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2840.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2842.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2834.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2848.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2861.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2860.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2860.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2861.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2854.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2851.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2851.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2851.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2848.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2848.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2848.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2849.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2846.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2845.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2841.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2842.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2844.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2843.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2844.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2844.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2846.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2846.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2847.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2845.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2840.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2840.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2839.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2836.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2833.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2836.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2831.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2829.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2827.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2828.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2827.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2829.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2832.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2829.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2827.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2826.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2825.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2833.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2833.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2829.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2824.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2821.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2808.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2811.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2813.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2810.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2805.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2807.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2810.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2815.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2810.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2810.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2812.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2806.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2808.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2803.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2811.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2808.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2809.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2802.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2793.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2801.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2806.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2803.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2800.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2798.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2797.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2795.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2796.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2799.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2798.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2797.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2796.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2790.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2784.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2787.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2794.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2795.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2799.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2800.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2800.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2798.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2804.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2809.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2808.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2801.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2803.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2794.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2795.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2799.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2799.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2798.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2797.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2796.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2803.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2806.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2803.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2798.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2799.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2795.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2795.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2793.00, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2789.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2793.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2788.50, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2789.25, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2782.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2775.75, "val" => -1 ),
             array( "close" => 2781.50, "val" => -1 )
    );
// _____________________________________________________________________

print_r( xrun( $demoArray ) );

// _____________________________________________________________________

?>
```

and produces the RSI-values, as specified.

### [PROOF :](https://tio.run/##1ZvrbtpKFIX/@ylGEVJApWV8HSNKqvMcURU5MIBVYiPb5JwU8ew5M@YWk@SUfKey1PwoCrBm77322peBdLVYPT9//bZarJzOVD/kfxVF8iTGIrGPXUe8/Nk9J64my7zUV2J8I7w4HH4JZV9cPSbL@pnPruj1L4JJBlMhgKkvHoBFksFcRImxRmKLPMZkxGA@oiT0mEoYJWHAYmNMBgo5aWDQGootbJNJI2UEi1jhRKxwIlbdjMkoptWNYH6bMNqVA9ZLYgqDCUCajBEsZtUdDxElMUu3cRLFFrPYAmbNZ9bYDFBsnYldCgsZkzDdCMb6ZBzRvJEKUKyXKDaoFEuAgppkq5pSdL6hPsnK1MCQNZeNfCauyKfW2tzwGJPGGoKx0REGNDaSgIBJOWTNPGSXzIBNnECi2AKmSZ9dHwK2KdDqhvduCGNO0l3ZZYXDnORX2j/AybhlGGwKqLrZTThgMyBgH8YFTMqwcwVs4gQ@tdYmLKIqkS2mG4pLUhhJt8/u3T5j0merGrXG2qvHKPHYDPDYhzoeW0M99jmX77XMJIqNqcQLWQX4tAJUi0yyT548VjiSSdllY9FlvcRlfVKyu6lkCZBsV5aKUkKk7LLCcSWFIZWwbx8kWzAku3dLnxaOZE4iGNvMJfr2QQ39VgsHwtxWnYyouFC6UVNQQzQD1FAxWMicjJgm0RC2lHgtUhIxa6i9qhhJWbEvCdUwYHkLGSVs55JwwZAtLhhWk5J1LuQku3XAfZJ2ZZ8xiTUJW5BiUoYqQTDcuVpcnvg0hTOgzbzBsQhhaMFQMZymPhtUTMrQyRjdOpQKWWxvNLwa1Rs5s3U2qdI8E/8U66wrOtOkSvqis9JFmk/FWLiB6G3qN3cmiySb67uk8eez5gj74iwvdDJZdGu8SErR@aGfrK1Okf/d24hLfgYDsczzlbBHHINKZ93dWTfGF3HhSc1DM62nwhOrPM2qUlS5mOtK7IJpcLcP0IRWR3FrzX6/va6ZvP4uPr942vzinl4aOa8ycLfOykU6q7pN2vpHI73RO94m06n1cVbkWdU41zIxydfZ@ZmiJ26OCeu9y8LKMHufTH6Yc8z5uaE6mzvn79v5bt76ysYpxu0buTnZ33wsN4vkUQud5ev5os67DX2SLCeiKNNmcgpdHkR3V@jpeqLPuXV@bfGg9m593npZmYSklX4wvG0afu0s7FWys2plU6XZXJTrB8NeWYokm9a/zJM0K52PKnNHX23daFvuS/LDP/tAbq@NJ3fWEyPVT@P9a/b00f/x7Kv4TZ5ZwnaeJffl4fQe8K3Q1brIDodfcsD2EmXs@@aJRdu8ZP9y/05R1sjLgZewe0ZUJ3mc117aXmWIaCR/cCjGNzC1bF9i9ml5B1Pr4ISrVbq5vLgnC236zTR9TKda3D@Jn7rIndcqKVM7Z6Rs2t4KvSy12LwFEDaGIweDk4@jXzhkO4ut2iwvHpJl@lP/hzumx3frx4F9FJ9qw73zVGybJL8cHGbcGmrH9ZGjiwgrTTc867O7fw@it8ePnK3jrAozzO6K7nFsH/9fS@3ht5vn538B)

```
Array (
[ 0] => Array ( [close] => 2859.5  [val] => -1 )
[ 1] => Array ( [close] => 2859    [val] => -1 )
[ 2] => Array ( [close] => 2859.75 [val] => -1 )
[ 3] => Array ( [close] => 2857.25 [val] => -1 )
[ 4] => Array ( [close] => 2860.25 [val] => -1 )
[ 5] => Array ( [close] => 2861.5  [val] => -1 )
[ 6] => Array ( [close] => 2860.75 [val] => -1 )
[ 7] => Array ( [close] => 2862    [val] => -1 ) 
[ 8] => Array ( [close] => 2856    [val] => -1 )
[ 9] => Array ( [close] => 2853.25 [val] => -1 )
[10] => Array ( [close] => 2852.5  [val] => -1 )
[11] => Array ( [close] => 2850.75 [val] => -1 )
[12] => Array ( [close] => 2854    [val] => -1 )
[13] => Array ( [close] => 2852    [val] => -1 )
[14] => Array ( [close] => 2847.75 [val] => -1 )
[15] => Array ( [close] => 2847    [val] => 30.645161290323 )
[16] => Array ( [close] => 2847    [val] => 28.925619834711 )
[17] => Array ( [close] => 2855.75 [val] => 47.945205479452 )
[18] => Array ( [close] => 2854    [val] => 41.13475177305  )
[19] => Array ( [close] => 2860    [val] => 48.125          )
[20] => Array ( [close] => 2866.5  [val] => 56.284153005464 ) [21] => Array ( [close] => 2866.75 [val] => 55.307262569832 ) [22] => Array ( [close] => 2866.25 [val] => 63.057324840764 ) [23] => Array ( [close] => 2865.75 [val] => 66.891891891892 ) [24] => Array ( [close] => 2868.75 [val] => 70.700636942675 ) [25] => Array ( [close] => 2862.75 [val] => 63.793103448276 ) [26] => Array ( [close] => 2863.75 [val] => 61.818181818182 ) [27] => Array ( [close] => 2863.75 [val] => 64.968152866242 ) [28] => Array ( [close] => 2859.75 [val] => 65.384615384615 ) [29] => Array ( [close] => 2854.25 [val] => 58.285714285714 ) [30] => Array ( [close] => 2858.25 [val] => 61.780104712042 ) [31] => Array ( [close] => 2858.75 [val] => 53.79746835443 ) [32] => Array ( [close] => 2862.5 [val] => 60.240963855422 ) [33] => Array ( [close] => 2868.5 [val] => 60.240963855422 ) [34] => Array ( [close] => 2887 [val] => 69.158878504673 ) [35] => Array ( [close] => 2889.25 [val] => 70.27027027027 ) [36] => Array ( [close] => 2883.75 [val] => 64.462809917355 ) [37] => Array ( [close] => 2887.5 [val] => 67.058823529412 ) [38] => Array ( [close] => 2888 [val] => 65.714285714286 ) [39] => Array ( [close] => 2884.5 [val] => 68.510638297872 ) [40] => Array ( [close] => 2883 [val] => 66.244725738397 ) [41] => Array ( [close] => 2882 [val] => 65.145228215768 ) [42] => Array ( [close] => 2879 [val] => 66.244725738397 ) [43] => Array ( [close] => 2881 [val] => 73.991031390135 ) [44] => Array ( [close] => 2881.5 [val] => 72.248803827751 ) [45] => Array ( [close] => 2884.75 [val] => 73.636363636364 ) [46] => Array ( [close] => 2887.75 [val] => 73.271889400922 ) [47] => Array ( [close] => 2885.75 [val] => 67.164179104478 ) [48] => Array ( [close] => 2886 [val] => 48.4375 ) [49] => Array ( [close] => 2882.25 [val] => 39.55223880597 ) [50] => Array ( [close] => 2878.25 [val] => 41.40625 ) [51] => Array ( [close] => 2876.5 [val] => 31.666666666667 ) [52] => Array ( [close] => 2874.75 [val] => 28.8 ) [53] => Array ( [close] => 2872 [val] => 29.508196721311 ) [54] => Array ( [close] => 2873.25 [val] => 33.884297520661 ) [55] => Array ( [close] => 2877.75 [val] => 43.703703703704 ) [56] => Array ( [close] => 2868.5 [val] => 36.875 ) [57] => Array ( [close] => 2863 [val] => 29.310344827586 ) [58] => Array ( [close] => 2863.5 [val] => 29.310344827586 ) [59] => Array ( [close] => 2861.25 [val] => 22.352941176471 ) [60] => Array ( [close] => 2862.25 [val] => 18.518518518519 ) [61] => Array ( [close] => 2863.25 [val] => 21.518987341772 ) [62] => Array ( [close] => 2862 [val] => 20.37037037037 ) [63] => Array ( [close] => 2855.75 [val] => 19.186046511628 ) [64] => Array ( [close] => 2853.5 [val] => 20 ) [65] => Array ( [close] => 2855.5 [val] => 24.698795180723 ) [66] => Array ( [close] => 2857.5 [val] => 29.341317365269 ) [67] => Array ( [close] => 2854.75 [val] => 29.341317365269 ) [68] => Array ( [close] => 2853.25 [val] => 26.190476190476 ) [69] => Array ( [close] => 2848.5 [val] => 15.384615384615 ) [70] => Array ( [close] => 2851 [val] => 25.352112676056 ) [71] => Array ( [close] => 2850.25 [val] => 29.268292682927 ) [72] => Array ( [close] => 2849 [val] => 26.984126984127 ) [73] => Array ( [close] => 2840.5 [val] => 22.516556291391 ) [74] => Array ( [close] => 2842 [val] => 23.529411764706 ) [75] => Array ( [close] => 2834 [val] => 17.67955801105 ) [76] => Array ( [close] => 2848 [val] => 37.931034482759 ) [77] => Array ( [close] => 2861.25 [val] => 54.230769230769 ) [78] => Array ( [close] => 2860.75 [val] => 55.731225296443 ) [79] => Array ( [close] => 2860.75 [val] => 54.285714285714 ) [80] => Array ( [close] => 2861.25 [val] => 53.138075313808 ) [81] => Array ( [close] => 2854.25 [val] => 49.609375 ) [82] => Array ( [close] => 2851.75 [val] => 48.846153846154 ) [83] => Array ( [close] => 2851.25 [val] => 52.263374485597 ) [84] => Array ( [close] => 2847 [val] => 46.8 ) [85] => Array ( [close] => 2847.75 [val] => 48 ) [86] => Array ( [close] => 2851.25 [val] => 51.737451737452 ) [87] => Array ( [close] => 2847 [val] => 55.371900826446 ) [88] => Array ( [close] => 2848 [val] => 55 ) [89] => Array ( [close] => 2848 [val] => 63.461538461538 ) [90] => Array ( [close] => 2848.25 [val] => 50.326797385621 ) [91] => Array ( [close] => 2849.5 [val] => 27.619047619048 ) [92] => Array ( [close] => 2846.25 [val] => 25 ) [93] => Array ( [close] => 2845.5 [val] => 24.36974789916 ) [94] => Array ( [close] => 2847.25 [val] => 27.41935483871 ) [95] => Array ( [close] => 2841.75 [val] => 28.813559322034 ) [96] => Array ( [close] => 2842 [val] => 32.110091743119 ) [97] => Array ( [close] => 2844.75 [val] => 38.983050847458 ) [98] => Array ( [close] => 2843 [val] => 42.592592592593 ) [99] => Array ( [close] => 2844 [val] => 43.119266055046 ) [100] => Array ( [close] => 2844 [val] => 34.736842105263 ) [101] => Array ( [close] => 2846.5 [val] => 48.863636363636 ) [102] => Array ( [close] => 2846 [val] => 45.348837209302 ) [103] => Array ( [close] => 2847.25 [val] => 48.351648351648 ) [104] => Array ( [close] => 2845.5 [val] => 44.329896907216 ) [105] => Array ( [close] => 2840.5 [val] => 33.928571428571 ) [106] => Array ( [close] => 2840.75 [val] => 39 ) [107] => Array ( [close] => 2839.25 [val] => 37.864077669903 ) [108] => Array ( [close] => 2836 [val] => 29.357798165138 ) [109] => Array ( [close] => 2833.5 [val] => 32.989690721649 ) [110] => Array ( [close] => 2836 [val] => 38.679245283019 ) [111] => Array ( [close] => 2831.25 [val] => 26.315789473684 ) [112] => Array ( [close] => 2829.25 [val] => 26.086956521739 ) [113] => Array ( [close] => 2827.75 [val] => 22.222222222222 ) [114] => Array ( [close] => 2828.75 [val] => 24.793388429752 ) [115] => Array ( [close] => 2827.5 [val] => 17.241379310345 ) [116] => Array ( [close] => 2829.75 [val] => 23.577235772358 ) [117] => Array ( [close] => 2832.25 [val] => 26.5625 ) [118] => Array ( [close] => 2829.25 [val] => 25.563909774436 ) [119] => Array ( [close] => 2827.5 [val] => 28.333333333333 ) [120] => Array ( [close] => 2826 [val] => 26.4 ) [121] => Array ( [close] => 2825.25 [val] => 27.049180327869 ) [122] => Array ( [close] => 2833 [val] => 45.714285714286 ) [123] => Array ( [close] => 2833.75 [val] => 50.375939849624 ) [124] => Array ( [close] => 2829.25 [val] => 40.425531914894 ) [125] => Array ( [close] => 2824.5 [val] => 40.425531914894 ) [126] => Array ( [close] => 2821.25 [val] => 39.041095890411 ) [127] => Array ( [close] => 2808.75 [val] => 30 ) [128] => Array ( [close] => 2811.75 [val] => 32.828282828283 ) [129] => Array ( [close] => 2813.5 [val] => 36 ) [130] => Array ( [close] => 2810.75 [val] => 31.188118811881 ) [131] => Array ( [close] => 2805.75 [val] => 25 ) [132] => Array ( [close] => 2804.5 [val] => 25.853658536585 ) [133] => Array ( [close] => 2804.25 [val] => 26.633165829146 ) [134] => Array ( [close] => 2807.5 [val] => 32.038834951456 ) [135] => Array ( [close] => 2810 [val] => 35.680751173709 ) [136] => Array ( [close] => 2815.25 [val] => 32.512315270936 ) [137] => Array ( [close] => 2810.25 [val] => 28.636363636364 ) [138] => Array ( [close] => 2810.75 [val] => 31.862745098039 ) [139] => Array ( [close] => 2812.75 [val] => 37.823834196891 ) [140] => Array ( [close] => 2806.5 [val] => 35.609756097561 ) [141] => Array ( [close] => 2808.5 [val] => 49.693251533742 ) [142] => Array ( [close] => 2803.75 [val] => 40.588235294118 ) [143] => Array ( [close] => 2811 [val] => 47.395833333333 ) [144] => Array ( [close] => 2808 [val] => 47.150259067358 ) [145] => Array ( [close] => 2809.5 [val] => 54.189944134078 ) [146] => Array ( [close] => 2802.5 [val] => 48.019801980198 ) [147] => Array ( [close] => 2793.5 [val] => 40.928270042194 ) [148] => Array ( [close] => 2804.25 [val] => 47.565543071161 ) [149] => Array ( [close] => 2804.25 [val] => 45.525291828794 ) [150] => Array ( [close] => 2801.5 [val] => 38.866396761134 ) [151] => Array ( [close] => 2804.25 [val] => 44.957983193277 ) [152] => Array ( [close] => 2806.5 [val] => 46.530612244898 ) [153] => Array ( [close] => 2803 [val] => 42.231075697211 ) [154] => Array ( [close] => 2800 [val] => 44.53781512605 ) [155] => Array ( [close] => 2798.75 [val] => 41.702127659574 ) [156] => Array ( [close] => 2797.75 [val] => 44.545454545455 ) [157] => Array ( [close] => 2795 [val] => 34.158415841584 ) [158] => Array ( [close] => 2796.5 [val] => 38.265306122449 ) [159] => Array ( [close] => 2799.25 [val] => 39.800995024876 ) [160] => Array ( [close] => 2798.25 [val] => 45.197740112994 ) [161] => Array ( [close] => 2797.75 [val] => 55.944055944056 ) [162] => Array ( [close] => 2796.25 [val] => 34.905660377358 ) [163] => Array ( [close] => 2790.75 [val] => 28.90625 ) [164] => Array ( [close] => 2784.25 [val] => 25.874125874126 ) [165] => Array ( [close] => 2787 [val] => 25.874125874126 ) [166] => Array ( [close] => 2794.5 [val] => 35.365853658537 ) [167] => Array ( [close] => 2795.25 [val] => 39.869281045752 ) [168] => Array ( [close] => 2799.25 [val] => 49.044585987261 ) [169] => Array ( [close] => 2800.75 [val] => 52.53164556962 ) [170] => Array ( [close] => 2800.75 [val] => 53.896103896104 ) [171] => Array ( [close] => 2804.5 [val] => 62.025316455696 ) [172] => Array ( [close] => 2798 [val] => 51.685393258427 ) [173] => Array ( [close] => 2804.75 [val] => 55.670103092784 ) [174] => Array ( [close] => 2809.75 [val] => 60.952380952381 ) [175] => Array ( [close] => 2808.75 [val] => 60.377358490566 ) [176] => Array ( [close] => 2801.5 [val] => 54.468085106383 ) [177] => Array ( [close] => 2803.5 [val] => 61.538461538462 ) [178] => Array ( [close] => 2794.5 [val] => 58.874458874459 ) [179] => Array ( [close] => 2795.5 [val] => 57.589285714286 ) [180] => Array ( [close] => 2799.75 [val] => 54.976303317536 ) [181] => Array ( [close] => 2799.5 [val] => 54.066985645933 ) [182] => Array ( [close] => 2798.5 [val] => 49.238578680203 ) [183] => Array ( [close] => 2797.75 [val] => 46.907216494845 ) [184] => Array ( [close] => 2796.5 [val] => 45.72864321608 ) [185] => Array ( [close] => 2803.75 [val] => 49.295774647887 ) [186] => Array ( [close] => 2806.5 [val] => 58.585858585859 ) [187] => Array ( [close] => 2803.25 [val] => 48.369565217391 ) [188] => Array ( [close] => 2798.75 [val] => 37.912087912088 ) [189] => Array ( [close] => 2799.5 [val] => 39.779005524862 ) [190] => Array ( [close] => 2795 [val] => 42.352941176471 ) [191] => Array ( [close] => 2795 [val] => 39.506172839506 ) [192] => Array ( [close] => 2793 [val] => 47.761194029851 ) [193] => Array ( [close] => 2789.25 [val] => 41.379310344828 ) [194] => Array ( [close] => 2793.75 [val] => 41.780821917808 ) [195] => Array ( [close] => 2788.5 [val] => 36.746987951807 ) [196] => Array ( [close] => 2789.25 [val] => 38.787878787879 ) [197] => Array ( [close] => 2782.75 [val] => 34.042553191489 ) [198] => Array ( [close] => 2775.75 [val] => 30.331753554502 ) [199] => Array ( [close] => 2781.5 [val] => 28.292682926829 ) )
```